# How to disable ScrollView

Tags: qt, qml, scrollview, qtquick2

I use a `ScrollView` for my `ListView` but **I need sometimes to disable it**.

A simple case would be something like that :

```
ScrollView {
    id: scroll
    ListView {
        model: DelegateModel {
            id: visualModel
            model: myModel //Model is set in the cpp
            delegate: Rectangle {
                    ...
                Button {
                    onClicked { //Important part
                        scroll.flickableItem.interactive = false //It doesn't work 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could I proceed ?

Comment: You don't need a scroll view to scroll a list view. You can set the list view interactive property to false.

Comment: What exactly do you want to disable? If you use a `ListView` together with a `ScrollView` the flickability is deactivated by default, afaik. So what should be deactivated, and what should still work?

Comment: @dtech I need to have a `ScrollBar` for my app.
@derM When a new Item is inserted in the list, the new Item will scale on the whole window and I don't want the user to be able to scroll down or up until he has done something. So I need to have an interactive Item (disabling `ListView` is not good for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *dtech* mentioned, the `ListView` has a built-in `Flickable` so to scroll, no `ScrollView` is needed for that. You can also add `ScrollBar`s to a `ListView` by using:

```
ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
```

However if you need to use the `ScrollView` as you want the old-school look-and-feel there is no documented way. Actually, when using `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` you have to resort to undocumented properties of the `Controls` quite often.

In this particular case, you could set the properties:

```
__horizontalScrollBar.enabled: false
__verticalScrollBar.enabled: false
__wheelAreaScrollSpeed: 0
```

Again: this is not documented and might change **if** there would be a newer version of the `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` - this however is unlikely, as right now the focus lies on the development of the modern `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` which are incompatible with the *documented API* of the `1.x`-versions

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I decided to migrate to `QtQuick.Controles 2.x` because I don't want to use a not documented function. Have a good day